# How to make this filter function only show me list elements that have the text-decoration of line through

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code set up where I have a input bellow which is a ul, when I type something in it, the ul will add a li using the characters I had written in the input, everything works fine, I even was able to find a filter with a search box where I can write which line I want to find, finally I added a function where when I click on a li that li will have a line go through the text (basically a text-decoration = "line-through";) the search box works perfectly with it, but now I want to add 2
more buttons one called Done and one called active, the done button is supposed to show me only the
li elements that have a line through their text while active shows me all the li elements that dont have a line through their text (meaning text-decoration = "none;").

My question is how do I make this function, I have no idea how to incorporate style into a filter like this.

```
function filter2() {
            var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, text , done;
            var input = document.getElementById("done");
            var filter = input.value;
            var ul = document.getElementById("list");
            var li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

            for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                text = a.textContent || a.innerText || a.style;
                if (text.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    li[i].style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    li[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of the `text.indexOf(filter) > -1` check use `li[i].style.textDecoration === "line-through"`

Comment: I will worship you until the end of time my lord!!!!!!!

Comment: No need for that, I'm just glad I could help. Good luck.